# How to update an arc on a canvas? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've been trying to make this pokeball designer but I cant figure out how to update the size of the ball. The user can click the size button to make the ball smaller, after it gets to 0.2 size it goes back to full size. I've got the button to update but I can't figure out how to make the arcs update on the canvas.

```
from tkinter import *


width = 500
height = 500

size = 1


def changeSize(): # sets the size of the pokeball
    global size
    global width
    global height
    if size != 0.2:
        size -= 0.1
    else:
        size = 1
    size = round(size, 2)
    print(size)
    sizeButton.config(text='Size: ' + str(size))
    width = width * size
    height = height * size
    canvas.update_idletasks()


window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window, width=width, height=height)
canvas.create_arc(10, 10, width - 10, height - 10, fill='red', style=PIESLICE, extent=180, width=10)
canvas.create_arc(10, 10, width - 10, height - 10, fill='white', style=PIESLICE, extent=180, width=10, start=180) 

sizeButton = Button(window, text='Size: ' + str(size), command=changeSize)
sizeButton.pack()
canvas.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: global variables are a very bad idea. Please make `size`, `width`, and `height` be input parameters to `changeSize()`. That is, instead of writing `def changeSize()` you can write, `def changeSize(size, width, height)`

Comment: You can use `canvas.coords(item_id, ...)` to resize those arcs but you need to save the item IDs of those arcs returned by `canvas.create_arc(...)`.

Comment: Also you should not update the global variables `width` and `height` inside `changeSize()`.

Answer (score 1):

- In line 41 and 42 add variable for `canvas.create_arc`
- in line 33 add `set_default` function. This will restart if value is
  1
- In line 28 and 29 add both `canvas.coords`
- in line 20 add `set_default()` callback

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *


width = 500
height = 500

size = 1


def changeSize(): # sets the size of the pokeball
    global size
    global width
    global height
    if size != 0.2:
        size -= 0.1
    else:
        size = 1
        set_default()          
            
    size = round(size, 2)
    print(size)
    sizeButton.config(text='Size: ' + str(size))
    width = width * size
    height = height * size
    
    canvas.coords(top_arc, size,size, width, height)
    canvas.coords(bottom_arc, size,size, width, height)
    canvas.update_idletasks()
    

def set_default():
    canvas.create_arc(10, 10, 490, 490, fill='red', style=PIESLICE, extent=180, width=10)
    canvas.create_arc(10, 10, 490, 490, fill='white', style=PIESLICE, extent=180, width=10, start=180)
    
     
window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window, width=width, height=height)
top_arc = canvas.create_arc(10, 10, width - 10, height - 10, fill='red', style=PIESLICE, extent=180, width=10)
bottom_arc = canvas.create_arc(10, 10, width - 10, height - 10, fill='white', style=PIESLICE, extent=180, width=10, start=180) 
 
sizeButton = Button(window, text='Size: ' + str(size), command=changeSize)
sizeButton.pack(side='bottom')
canvas.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot at the start:

[image]

Screenshot ball resizing: and position;

[image]

Screenshot ball at x=0, y=0:

[image]

Screenshot back to restart:

[image]